# Is it possible to take control over a process by knowing the PID of the Process?

Tags: java, process

I want to take control over a process in java and watch if the process e.g. starts a another process. Is there a way to do that in java?

Comment: No. There is no way "to take control over a process by PID". I'm not at all certain what that means; but Java is not a tool like gdb where you can "hook" into native applications.

Comment: But is there a java library to watch active processes? And get their names?

Comment: `jps` for Java processes. If you want native processes, then maybe; but it would be a third party tool.